# Recuperate data from List<HashMap>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hashmap

Until now i don't know how to solve this issue. I want to view content of `List<HashMap>` in DataTable.

*Note :* **I don't have map as property in my Bean**

**Class Persistant :**

```
@Entity
public class Produit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3352484919001942398L;
/**
 * 
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String module;
private String produit;

//getter&&setter
```

Class Dao:

```
public  List<Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>> parProduit(String cat) {
 .......
HashMap<Integer, List<Produit>> legaux = new HashMap<Integer, List<Produit>>();
........
List<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>>(legaux.entrySet());

    return entries;
    }
```

**ClassService** : here is method which return HashMap.

```
public List<Entry<Integer, List<Produit>>> allProduit(String produit){          
 .....
                                                                     }
```

**The flow:**

```
<view-state id="accueil" view="accueil.xhtml">
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="moduleService.allProduit(module.getProduit())"
            result="viewScope.result" />
    </on-render>

</view-state>
```

In page xhtml what should i do to recuperate data ?? any idea will welcome.

Comment: Why have you ignored the answer to use `List<Entry>` as shown in the duplicate link to your previous question? Now you have a completely different data model which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: when i use List<Entry> i get error about serialisable

Comment: That's a different problem which needs to be fixed individually irrespective of the current problem.

Comment: so you suggest that i should use List<Entry> rather than List<HashMap>

Comment: That's not a suggestion. That's an answer. Just do `return new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());` in order to give the view exactly the model it expects and can present. Oh, why did you delete the previous question? Deletions account towards question ban.

Comment: Now when i try this code i get `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.HashMap$Node`

Comment: As mentioned above, that is a different question...

Comment: Instead of using; `map.entrySet()`, is it possible to use `map.values()` which will return a Collection containing all of the map's values.